# Ray has weird time consuming

Tags: python, ray

I have a tiny Ray pipeline like this:

```
import ray
import numpy as np
import time

@ray.remote
class PersonDetector:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = self._init_model()
    
    def _init_model(self):
        s = np.random.random([100, 4])
        return s

    def infer(self, img):
        b = self.model[0:np.random.randint(100), :]
        # random batch boxes
        print(b.shape)
        time.sleep(4)
        return b

@ray.remote
class KptsDetector:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = self._init_model()
    
    def _init_model(self):
        s = np.random.random([100, 17])
        return s
    
    def infer(self, img, boxes):
        sh1 = boxes.shape[0]
        kpts = self.model[0: sh1, :]
        time.sleep(2)
        return kpts


@ray.remote
class HandDetector:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = self._init_model()
    
    def _init_model(self):
        s = np.random.random([100, 4])
        return s

    def infer(self, img):
        b = self.model[0:np.random.randint(100), :]
        # random batch boxes
        data = {}
        data['hands'] = b
        time.sleep(3)
        return data

@ray.remote
def gather_all(hands, kpts):
    t0 = time.time()
    if isinstance(hands, dict):
        print(f'in hands info: {hands.keys()}')
        hands = hands['hands']
    if hands.shape[0] > kpts.shape[0]:
        out = hands.copy()
        out[:kpts.shape[0], :] += kpts[..., :4]
    else:
        out = kpts.copy()[..., :4]
        out[:hands.shape[0], :] += hands
    print(f'[gather time] {time.time() - t0}')
    return out

# how to written DAG in classes?
P = PersonDetector.remote()
K = KptsDetector.remote()
H = HandDetector.remote()

t0 = time.time()
img = []
boxes = P.infer.remote(img)
hands = H.infer.remote(img)
kpts = K.infer.remote(img, boxes)

# out = gather.remote(hands, kpts)
out = gather_all.remote(hands, kpts)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1 - t0)

out = ray.get(out)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t0)
print(t2 - t1)
print(out.shape)
```

I using `time.sleep()` for fake time consuming. As you can see, the HandDetector should running in a sub process, so the whole time should be 6s.

But I got (you can have a try on your computer):

```
6.45377516746521
6.4489240646362305
```

Why there are 0.4s time more?

Comment: The processing time and overhead?

Comment: @aaron You can take a look at my graph, Hand is running semuteounsly along with Person + Kpts, so it's time should hindden by Person + Kpts, overall 6 s. The 400ms overhead is tooo much, I want to know why and how to eliminate it.

Comment: Try without `sleep` and with `sleep(0)`, and then share the results.

Comment: @aaron Dude...... I just mimik time consuming for my real model..... My question is about the overhead, not sleep time cost.....

Comment: Some overhead is unavoidable. There is no solvable problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you posted the same question to the Ray GitHub ([link to comment](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/7511#issuecomment-1229114440)). I am copying the [answer](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/7511#issuecomment-1229125792) here so other StackOverflow users can benefit.

[@robertnishihara](https://github.com/robertnishihara):
You are recreating the actors every time you call do_it, and there is some overhead to creating actors (it starts a new Python process).

If you rewrite it as follows, the overhead drops.

```py
import ray
import numpy as np
import time

ray.init()

@ray.remote
class PersonDetector:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = self._init_model()
    
    def _init_model(self):
        s = np.random.random([100, 4])
        return s

    def infer(self, img):
        b = self.model[0:np.random.randint(100), :]
        # random batch boxes
        print(b.shape)
        time.sleep(4)
        return b

@ray.remote
class KptsDetector:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = self._init_model()
    
    def _init_model(self):
        s = np.random.random([100, 17])
        return s
    
    def infer(self, img, boxes):
        sh1 = boxes.shape[0]
        kpts = self.model[0: sh1, :]
        time.sleep(2)
        return kpts


@ray.remote
class HandDetector:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = self._init_model()
    
    def _init_model(self):
        s = np.random.random([100, 4])
        return s

    def infer(self, img):
        b = self.model[0:np.random.randint(100), :]
        # random batch boxes
        data = {}
        data['hands'] = b
        time.sleep(3)
        return data

@ray.remote
def gather_all(hands, kpts):
    t0 = time.time()
    if isinstance(hands, dict):
        print(f'in hands info: {hands.keys()}')
        hands = hands['hands']
    if hands.shape[0] > kpts.shape[0]:
        out = hands.copy()
        out[:kpts.shape[0], :] += kpts[..., :4]
    else:
        out = kpts.copy()[..., :4]
        out[:hands.shape[0], :] += hands
    print(f'[gather time] {time.time() - t0}')
    return out


def do_it(i, P, K, H):
    t0 = time.time()
    img = []
    boxes = P.infer.remote(img)
    hands = H.infer.remote(img)
    kpts = K.infer.remote(img, boxes)

    # out = gather.remote(hands, kpts)
    out = gather_all.remote(hands, kpts)
    t1 = time.time()
    out_value = ray.get(out)
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f'{i}. {t2 - t1}')
    print(out_value.shape)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    P = PersonDetector.remote()
    K = KptsDetector.remote()
    H = HandDetector.remote()    
    for i in range(3):
        do_it(i, P, K, H)
```

In this case, I get the output

```
(PersonDetector pid=36472) (35, 4)
0. 7.073965072631836
(95, 4)
(PersonDetector pid=36472) (34, 4)
(gather_all pid=36421) in hands info: dict_keys(['hands'])
(gather_all pid=36421) [gather time] 6.890296936035156e-05
1. 6.016530275344849
(47, 4)
(PersonDetector pid=36472) (87, 4)
(gather_all pid=36421) in hands info: dict_keys(['hands'])
(gather_all pid=36421) [gather time] 9.608268737792969e-05
2. 6.006845235824585
(88, 4)

(gather_all pid=36421) in hands info: dict_keys(['hands'])
(gather_all pid=36421) [gather time] 9.870529174804688e-05
```